# Sorting Bibliography Alphabetically at the end of each chapter

Tags: natbib, chapterbib

I need to sort the bibliography at the end of each chapter that are imported by using \include command in main thesis file. Each chapter contains its bibliography and respective style (plainnat).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[semicolon,round,authoryear,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}  %bibliography at the end of each chapter
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{1.5pt} 
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibch1.bib}


@article{hamid2011potential,
    title={Potential risk factors associated with human encephalitis: application of canonical correlation analysis},
    author={Hamid, Jemila S and Meaney, Christopher and Crowcroft, Natasha S and Granerod, Julia and Beyene, Joseph},
    journal={BMC medical research methodology},
    volume={11},
    number={1},
    pages={120},
    year={2011},
    publisher={BioMed Central}
}
@article{hattie1985methodology,
    title={Methodology review: assessing unidimensionality of tests and ltenls},
    author={Hattie, John},
    journal={Applied psychological measurement},
    volume={9},
    number={2},
    pages={139--164},
    year={1985},
    publisher={Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA}
}
@article{kirk1973numerical,
    title={On the numerical approximation of the bivariate normal (tetrachoric) correlation coefficient},
    author={Kirk, David B},
    journal={Psychometrika},
    volume={38},
    number={2},
    pages={259--268},
    year={1973},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{lee2015access,
    title={Access to finance for innovative SMEs since the financial crisis},
    author={Lee, Neil and Sameen, Hiba and Cowling, Marc},
    journal={Research policy},
    volume={44},
    number={2},
    pages={370--380},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibch2.bib}
@article{samuel2015effect,
    title={The effect of credit risk on the performance of commercial banks in Nigeria},
    author={Samuel, Olawale Luqman},
    journal={African Journal of Accounting, Auditing and Finance},
    volume={4},
    number={1},
    pages={29--52},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Inderscience Publishers (IEL)}
}
@article{froot1998risk,
    title={Risk management, capital budgeting, and capital structure policy for financial institutions: an integrated approach},
    author={Froot, Kenneth A and Stein, Jeremy C},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={47},
    number={1},
    pages={55--82},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{salas2002credit,
    title={Credit risk in two institutional regimes: Spanish commercial and savings banks},
    author={Salas, Vicente and Saurina, Jesus},
    journal={Journal of Financial Services Research},
    volume={22},
    number={3},
    pages={203--224},
    year={2002},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{cornett2011liquidity,
    title={Liquidity risk management and credit supply in the financial crisis},
    author={Cornett, Marcia Millon and McNutt, Jamie John and Strahan, Philip E and Tehranian, Hassan},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={101},
    number={2},
    pages={297--312},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{aebi2012risk,
    title={Risk management, corporate governance, and bank performance in the financial crisis},
    author={Aebi, Vincent and Sabato, Gabriele and Schmid, Markus},
    journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume={36},
    number={12},
    pages={3213--3226},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}

\section{Chapter 1}
%chapters are imported using \include command, having bibliography (style) at the end of each chapter
All physical systems are nonlinear in nature. Nonlinear control design technique like backstepping considers the nonlinearity also during design. The 1991 Bode lecture at IEEE CDC, held by Kokotovic was devoted to backstepping and in 1992 kanellakopoulos presented a mathematical toolkit for design of backstepping control laws. During the following year text books by Kristic \citet{hamid2011potential} Freeman , Kokotovic and Sepulchre were published.

The discrete-time feedback control techniques such as feedback linearization, backstepping and state dependent riccati equation methods in \citet{hattie1985methodology}\citet{kirk1973numerical} and  missile autopilot design was also considered in \citet{kirk1973numerical} .The application of discrete time backstepping  to  various systems is given in \citet{hattie1985methodology}\citet{lee2015access}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibch1}

\section{Chapter 2}

The backstepping control technique is found to have a lot of advantages compared to feedback linearization and gain scheduling. Backstepping does not require exact model for design \citet{cornett2011liquidity}\citet{salas2002credit}.The backstepping technique can solve tracking and regulator problems. It can also provide dead beat control and exact tracking of any desired trajectory in finite time and exploits the flexibility offered by \cite{samuel2015effect} lower order and scalar systems. Backstepping technique takes advantage of useful nonlinearities which help in making the Lyapunov derivative negative definite \citet{aebi2012risk}.The discrete backstepping technique has been applied to roll control and sideslip angle control of a reusable launch vehicle. The system is discretized first and then the controller is developed step by step and has given very good \cite{froot1998risk} tracking and stabilizing performance.

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.

% If you comment hyperref and then uncomment it, you should delete
% egpaper.aux before re-running latex.  (Or just hit 'q' on the first latex
% run, let it finish, and you should be clear).
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibch2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with [biber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber). There are many options available and you can configure it as you like. In your case the option `refsection=chapter` combined with the heading `subbibliography` at the `\printbibliography` command in each chapter does what you want. You can just add your .bib-Files with `\addbibresource{yourbib.bib}` in the preamble and reference to your sources in the appropriate chapters.

---

You can compile the code by:

1. pdflatex document.tex
2. biber document
3. pdflatex document.tex
4. pdflatex document.tex

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibch1.bib}
@article{hamid2011potential,
    title={Potential risk factors associated with human encephalitis: application of canonical correlation analysis},
    author={Hamid, Jemila S and Meaney, Christopher and Crowcroft, Natasha S and Granerod, Julia and Beyene, Joseph},
    journal={BMC medical research methodology},
    volume={11},
    number={1},
    pages={120},
    year={2011},
    publisher={BioMed Central}
}
@article{hattie1985methodology,
    title={Methodology review: assessing unidimensionality of tests and ltenls},
    author={Hattie, John},
    journal={Applied psychological measurement},
    volume={9},
    number={2},
    pages={139--164},
    year={1985},
    publisher={Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA}
}
@article{kirk1973numerical,
    title={On the numerical approximation of the bivariate normal (tetrachoric) correlation coefficient},
    author={Kirk, David B},
    journal={Psychometrika},
    volume={38},
    number={2},
    pages={259--268},
    year={1973},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{lee2015access,
    title={Access to finance for innovative SMEs since the financial crisis},
    author={Lee, Neil and Sameen, Hiba and Cowling, Marc},
    journal={Research policy},
    volume={44},
    number={2},
    pages={370--380},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibch2.bib}
@article{samuel2015effect,
    title={The effect of credit risk on the performance of commercial banks in Nigeria},
    author={Samuel, Olawale Luqman},
    journal={African Journal of Accounting, Auditing and Finance},
    volume={4},
    number={1},
    pages={29--52},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Inderscience Publishers (IEL)}
}
@article{froot1998risk,
    title={Risk management, capital budgeting, and capital structure policy for financial institutions: an integrated approach},
    author={Froot, Kenneth A and Stein, Jeremy C},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={47},
    number={1},
    pages={55--82},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{salas2002credit,
    title={Credit risk in two institutional regimes: Spanish commercial and savings banks},
    author={Salas, Vicente and Saurina, Jesus},
    journal={Journal of Financial Services Research},
    volume={22},
    number={3},
    pages={203--224},
    year={2002},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{cornett2011liquidity,
    title={Liquidity risk management and credit supply in the financial crisis},
    author={Cornett, Marcia Millon and McNutt, Jamie John and Strahan, Philip E and Tehranian, Hassan},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={101},
    number={2},
    pages={297--312},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{aebi2012risk,
    title={Risk management, corporate governance, and bank performance in the financial crisis},
    author={Aebi, Vincent and Sabato, Gabriele and Schmid, Markus},
    journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume={36},
    number={12},
    pages={3213--3226},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{texch1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]
\nocite{hamid2011potential, hattie1985methodology, kirk1973numerical,%
lee2015access}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{texch2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]
\nocite{samuel2015effect, froot1998risk, salas2002credit, cornett2011liquidity,%
aebi2012risk}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibch1.bib}
\addbibresource{bibch2.bib}

\begin{document}

\include{texch1}

\include{texch2}

\end{document}
```

---

This is what you get:

[image: The result]